# which xcode template I should use to test objective c code

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I started learning IOS development a month ago. Normally, I use a `single View Application` in order to develop my IOS application.

Now, I just need to test some features in objective c like polymorphism, encapsulation and inheritance. However, I don't know which xcode template I should use for that.

Could you help me please?

Sorry for this rookie question

#### Edit

In other words, I don't want to test those features on an IOS application. Instead, I need a template like the one you would recommend to a new c++ student.

Comment: Single View or any template are just fine!

Comment: Dear Thanh-Nhon NGUYEN,
Thanks for your comment. I would prefer a template in which I don't need to fire the simulator every time I need to check something. Isn't there any simpler template?
Thanks in advance

Comment: When you say **TEST** do you mean Unit Testing or you just want to run your application and print stuff to the console?

Comment: Dear Popeye, thanks for your comment. I need to print stuff to the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below links. It will help to study all beginning level tutorials.

http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-course/

and for objective C testing. you can use commend Line tool.

[image]

Comment: Dear PREMKUMAR, thanks for your answer. By `commendline template`, did you mean `Command Line Tool` or `Cocoa Application`? Thanks in advance

Comment: I told Commend line tool. Its like our Terminal.